# Assigning constant to a variable causes 2 loads?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, profiling

This is done in C#, profiler used is Intel Vtune. Code compiled in Release configuration.
The following line of code:

```
_smalestRangeSq = float.MaxValue;
```

where _smalestRangeSq is a class field, result in this

```
movss xmm0, dword ptr [rip+0x9ee]                   
movss dword ptr [rsi+0x58], xmm0
```

And apparently it consumes a lot of time performing stores. Can anyone explain for me why?

Comment: Does it really where your application spend most of it's time?

Comment: Looks like the x86 JIT does a much better job: `mov dword ptr ds:[0EFCC24h],7F7FFFFFh`

Comment: the (=) sign in value types often creates a new copy of object and signs it to operand. there is no difference when right hand of operator is variable or constant.

Comment: @mehrdadsafa your statement is false, the values from `const` fields are used as-is, which is very different from `static readonly` fields. `float.MaxValue` is `const`, and it's usage is the same as if you had written `(float)3.40282346638528859e+38` directly in the source code.